# Структура файлов Express проекта с подсайтами

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Я хочу понять, какие могут быть структуры файлов для проекта.
У меня есть домен допустим `example.com`, на нем расположен основной сайт (допустим сейчас это одностраничник с какой-то информацией) и есть еще "подсайты", то есть `example.com/test`, допустим это будет тоже какой-то однастраничник (а может и нет..).
То есть у сайтов будет как минимум файлы css/fileName.css, scss/fileName.scss, js/fileName.js.

Я хочу понять как это все должно быть в папках.

Я понимаю что на этот вопрос не возможно дать объективный ответ, но я хочу услышать варианты или ссылочку, где я могу задать данный вопрос.

Comment: Подсайты на отдельных доменах (`test.example.com`) и отдельными приложениями. Избежите огромного количества проблем.

Comment: Вроде бы и да.. Но, а если допустим это в дальнейшем будет аля портфолио?

Comment: Просто в основном там один "html" файл и для него по одному js и css файлу, ради этого делать отдельный поддомен..

Comment: А чем это тогда подсайт и зачем тут вообще нужен экспресс?

Comment: Я думал это называется подсайт, а что это тогда? Экспресс чтобы уйти от PHP бэка, да и мне больше нравится, что я могу больше контролировать все.